# lmfit: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, data-fitting, lmfit

I'm using lmfit to fit a "complex" model onto experimental data.

I define the parameters of the model like this:

```
def model(t, y0, h, A1, x1, s1, A2, x2, s2, A3, x3, s3, A4, x4, s4):

        y = y0 + h * (
                      A1 * (0.5 + 0.5 * erf((t - x1) / (s1 * 2**0.5))) +
                      A2 * (0.5 + 0.5 * erf((t - x2) / (s2 * 2**0.5))) +
                      A3 * (0.5 + 0.5 * erf((t - x3) / (s3 * 2**0.5))) +
                      A4 * (0.5 + 0.5 * erf((t - x4) / (s4 * 2**0.5)))
                      )
        return y


mod = Model(model)

# sys.setrecursionlimit(150000)

# Set the parameters, define their bounds and their relations
mod.set_param_hint('y0', value=self.spin_y0.value())
mod.set_param_hint('h', value=self.spin_h.value())

mod.set_param_hint('A1', value=self.spin_A1.value(), min=0, max=1),
mod.set_param_hint('x1', value=self.spin_x1.value(), min=0, max=self.x[-1])
mod.set_param_hint('s1', value=self.spin_s1.value(), min=0)

mod.set_param_hint('A2', value=self.spin_A2.value(), min=0, max=1),
mod.set_param_hint('x2', value=self.spin_x2.value(), min=0, max=self.x[-1])
mod.set_param_hint('s2', value=self.spin_s2.value(), min=0)

mod.set_param_hint('A3', value=self.spin_A3.value(), min=0, max=1),
mod.set_param_hint('x3', value=self.spin_x3.value(), min=0, max=self.x[-1])
mod.set_param_hint('s3', value=self.spin_s3.value(), min=0)

mod.set_param_hint('A4', value=self.spin_A4.value(), min=0, max=1),
mod.set_param_hint('x4', value=self.spin_x4.value(), min=0, max=self.x[-1])
mod.set_param_hint('s4', value=self.spin_s4.value(), min=0)

mod.set_param_hint('A1', expr='1-A2-A3-A4')
mod.set_param_hint('A2', expr='1-A1-A3-A4')
mod.set_param_hint('A3', expr='1-A1-A2-A4')
mod.set_param_hint('A4', expr='1-A1-A2-A3')

mod.make_params()

# Fit the data !
result = mod.fit(self.y, t=self.x)
```

I use spinBoxes to get the values which will be used as initial values (my program is a GUI).

I have a problem with A1, A2, A3 and A4. They are dependent, and their sum must be equal to 1.

If I comment

```
mod.set_param_hint('A1', expr='1-A2-A3-A4')
mod.set_param_hint('A2', expr='1-A1-A3-A4')
mod.set_param_hint('A3', expr='1-A1-A2-A4')
mod.set_param_hint('A4', expr='1-A1-A2-A3
```

The parameters vary between 0 and 1 (I define this range when I define the parameters), but their sum is never equal to 1.

When these lines are not commented, I have the following exception:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/lmfit/minimizer.py", line 255, in __update_paramval
    self.__update_paramval(dep)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/lmfit/minimizer.py", line 250, in __update_paramval
    if getattr(par, 'expr', None) is not None:
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

I don't really know what it means. I tried to increase the maximum recursion depth, but it changed nothing.

Do you have any idea about what is the problem ?

Comment: If your program relies heavily on recursion, you'll probably hit it no matter what. Try reconfiguring it into a loop if possible, or switch to a language that supports tail-call optimization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for future me and other persons looking for a solution, I found one. I used scimin.fmin_slsqp to do the job. Here is a sample of code:

```
def model(t, params):

    y0, h, A1, x1, s1, A2, x2, s2, A3, x3, s3, A4, x4, s4 = [value for value in params]

    y = y0 + h * (
                  A1 * (0.5 + 0.5 * erf((t - x1) / (s1 * 2**0.5))) +
                  A2 * (0.5 + 0.5 * erf((t - x2) / (s2 * 2**0.5))) +
                  A3 * (0.5 + 0.5 * erf((t - x3) / (s3 * 2**0.5))) +
                  A4 * (0.5 + 0.5 * erf((t - x4) / (s4 * 2**0.5)))
                 )

    return y


def sum_residuals(params):  # the function we want to minimize

    y0, h, A1, x1, s1, A2, x2, s2, A3, x3, s3, A4, x4, s4 = [value for value in params]

    return sum((list_y - model(list_x, params))**2)


def constraints(params):

    y0, h, A1, x1, s1, A2, x2, s2, A3, x3, s3, A4, x4, s4 = [value for value in params]

    return 1 - (A1 + A2 + A3 + A4)


pfit = scimin.fmin_slsqp(sum_residuals,
                         p0,
                         f_eqcons=constraints,
                         bounds=bounds,
                         iprint=0,
                         iter=300
                        )
```

Where p0 is a sequence of the initial parameters.
However, fmin_slsqp doesn't return a covariance matrix, I couldn't calculate confidence intervals on the fitted parameters. For that I used the bootstrap method.